# "Like X but a little less Y and a little more Z"

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests, comparisons

> *Like X but a (little/lot) less Y and a (little/lot) more Z.*

Is there a name for this type of comparison? It's not really an analogy (or is it?) It's not a simile or a [dissimile](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Dissimile).

> Examples of usage:
>   - Detest is a lot like despising but a little less personal and a little more abstract
>   - To the eye, he seems to be a lot like Margy Time, but a little less power and a little more speed and flash ([context link](http://wranglernetwork.com/news/the-morning-line-tulsa-day-1/))
>   - Quixote is pronounced like peyote but a little less pee and a little more keex

Any suggestions? I added [idiom-requests](/questions/tagged/idiom-requests) as well, as the answer *could* be an idiom, but if there's a definitive answer that's not an idiom, then please feel free to remove the tag (and this note).

PS: Apologies in advance for any lost productivity caused by the TVTropes link.

Comment: Can you give specific examples of what you're talking about?

Comment: Added a few examples in main post.

Answer (score 1):

I'm inclined toward the phrase: *[complex comparison](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=complex%20comparison&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccomplex%20comparison%3B%2Cc0)*.

*A is like X* is a simple comparison, or simile. It is simple because the comparison is between a homogenous range of qualities ignoring differences:

> My dog is like his dog because it has brown fur.
>
> iPads are like laptop computers, because they are self contained
>   units.

By introducing heterogenous qualities (*but*) and dissimilarities (*less Y and more Z*) we complicate the comparison for a clearer definition:

> My dog is like your dog, **but** a little *less* threatening and a lot *more* noisy.
>
> iPads are like laptop computers, **but** a lot *less* bulky and a little *more* convenient.

Weaving more *complex* dissimilarities into the comparison helps people discover the true nature of my Pomeranian in comparison to his Pit Bull, or the actual qualities of an iPad in comparison to a laptop computer.

[Complex](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=complex&allowed_in_frame=0)

> 1650s, "composed of parts," from French complexe "complicated,
>   complex, intricate" (17c.),
>
> from Latin complexus "surrounding, encompassing," past participle of
>   complecti "to encircle, embrace," in transferred use, "to hold fast,
>   master, comprehend,"
>
> from com- "***with***" (see com-) + plectere "to ***weave***, braid,
>   twine, entwine," from PIE *plek-to-, from root *plek- "to plait" (see
>   ply (v.1)).
>
> ***Emphasis*** mine

---

www.etymonline.com

Answer (score 0):

Take the following link as an example:
http://www.grammarly.com/handbook/sentences/parallelism/4/parallelism-with-not-only-but-also/
Not only ... but also ... > Parallelism / Correlative Conjunction

I think the "Like X but a (little/lot) less Y and a (little/lot) more Z" is similar to it.
When you remove the X, Y, and Z; you get no meaning. Same with Not only ... but also ...

They both are comparison of things.
It is a saying to compare things.

Hence, I think that the answer may simply be: Comparative Conjunction.

Hehe